# Apache POI 4.1 - new XSSFWorkbook causes POIXMLException: Strict OOXML isn't currently supported

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am aware that about 3–4 years ago, there was an issue ([ASF bug 57699](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57699)) with reading `.xlsx` files (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37749841/org-apache-poi-poixmlexception-strict-ooxml-isnt-currently-supported-please-se).

Today I tried Apache POI 4.1, but I still see bug #57699 with the following 1 line of code:

```java
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(uploadFile.getInputStream());
```

The exception message is below:

```
org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: Strict OOXML isn't currently supported, please see bug #57699
```

Are there any workaround solutions with bug #57699 besides using different formats?

Answer (score 1):

I use a slightly modified version of @PJFanning's ooxml converter https://github.com/pjfanning/ooxml-strict-converter to check for and convert strict Excel workbooks (as streams) and then read them with POI.  In limited testing it seems to work, although the files I have are pretty straight-forward.

To detect, I wrap the InputStream with a BufferedInputStream and then peek into the XML inside the Zip file (xlsx files are actually a collection of XML files in a zip file) looking for the namespace markers that indicate that it is in strict format.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/pjfanning/excel-streaming-reader has some support for reading xlsx files in this format.

Support is still evolving, it is recommended you use the latest available excel-streaming-reader version if you are interested in supporting OOXML Strict format.

When reading xlsx files, excel-streaming-reader automatically recognises that the file is in Strict OOXML format.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software in my answers?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5329/513819)